# TYPO3 v11.5 #1578950324 RuntimeException - The given page record is invalid. Missing uid. Backendmodul

Tags: typo3, backend, typo3-extensions, typo3-11.x

After upgrading to TYPO3 v11.5, I get this error in my extensions backend module:

> 1578950324 RuntimeException

> The given page record is invalid. Missing uid.

So I digged a little deeper and found out that this has to do with using the `f:be.tableList` ViewHelper.

In my BE module I use the ViewHelper like this:

```
<f:be.tableList
    tableName="tx_myext_domain_model_mymodel"
    storagePid="1"
    fieldList="{0: 'column1', 1: 'column_2'}"
    sortField="column1"
    enableControlPanels="true"
    clickTitleMode="edit" />
```

Since I register my backend module with `'navigationComponentId' => '',` ([as mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/BackendModules/BackendModuleApi/Index.html)) I get this error. But the page tree or something else isn't helpful at this point, so I don't want to show them.

(If I show the page tree with `'navigationComponentId' => 'TYPO3/CMS/Backend/PageTree/PageTreeElement'`, this error disappears)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the ViewHelper checks if the user has access rights via checking if the PID is in the mountPoint. I think this is important and not a bug. Fixing that issue could be hard, because how to check the mountPoint permissions if I don't know the PID. (maybe in the ViewHelper: check against the storagePid?)

But if you disable the page tree, there is no PID to check against.

So I also found out, the current PID is fetched while TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility looks for a given id like this:

```
$value = $_POST[$var] ?? $_GET[$var] ?? null;
```

I didn't found a way to set the pid in my Extbase Controller, so I did it easily this way in my listAction:

```
if( TYPO3_MODE == 'BE' ) {
    // if is in the BE-module, set PID to prevent customer authentication check error
    $_POST['id'] = 1;
}
```

(In this case, I set the PID to my rootpage.)

If someone has a better solution, don't hesitate to post it to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled the page tree for the backend module? If yes - that's the problem! The settings `inheritNavigationComponentFromMainModule => false` leads to the error.

Comment: Yes, but I won't confuse the user by showing the page tree without any useful function on it in the backend module. The use case inside the backend module has nothing to do with the page tree. (I want to have a better UX)
The second point is, the user has to choose a page before accessing the backend module, otherwise the error still occurs. This isn't set e. g. when after login directly switching to the backend module.